# Software to validate DTD schema

Tags: validation, schema, dtd

I'm trying to find software that helps check that a DTD schema is written in a valid structure.

However, pretty much all I can find are articles on how to validate an XML document against a DTD schema, but since we are creating/editing a rather extensive DTD we really want to be sure that we're creating a valid schema.

All I've turned up so far is XMLSpy by Altova - but it does a lot of other things, and I was hoping to find something leaner and simpler.

Comment: What do you mean by "written in a valid structure"?  Do you mean "conformant to the XML spec"? (The XML spec defines the notion of validity for documents, but not for DTDs.)  Do you mean "written in a way that makes sense, with no unreachable or unused elements except possibly the root, no references to undeclared elements, ..."? Or ... what?

Comment: @C.M.Sperberg-McQueen - valid as in structurally valid for a DTD - no unpaired braces or brackets and other malformities. DTD language maybe structurally simple compared to XML, but given the length of a DTD, it is very easy to introduce errors which then cause FrameMaker to have a fit. In any event, we've found LiquidXML provides syntax highlighting and validation for DTD.

Comment: @mzjn - for some reason, I never found that question in my searches... thanks (and I agree, mine is a duplicate)

Comment: @HorusKol, yes of course it's easy to introduce syntax errors into DTDs.  Suggesting that you express yourself clearly and avoid the misuse of well defined technical terms is not the same as saying there is no problem -- it's the same as saying that if you don't express yourself clearly, no one will know what problem you are trying (but failing) to talk about.

Comment: What is not clear about asking to how to check if a DTD is valid?